# How to prevent my router from setting itself as a DNS server?

Tags: router, dns

I have a TP Link router (Archer C6 with v1.3.6 firmware version), even though I configured optional DNS addresses, it keeps setting itself as the 2nd DNS address.

How can I prevent it?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/tp-link/tp-link-archer-c6/configure-dhcp/) help ?

Comment: @Anonymous, this does not explain how to prevent the router from adding its own IP address as a DNS when handing out IP addresses to clients via DHCP, only how to add additional DNS servers. Unfortunately, I don’t think there’s a solution except for updated or third party firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I can get away if I enter my custom IP twice: both as primary address and also as my secondary address, weird..

Answer (score 0):

If after entering your preferred optional DNS servers (under Advanced > Network > DHCP Server) and clicking save, the router immediately sets something else as the secondary DNS, then it sounds like a firmware upgrade and/or factory reset might help.

Firmware upgrade:

1. Download the latest version for your model at http://tplinkwifi.net/
2. Upload the firmware to the router (Advanced > System Tools > Firmware Upgrade)

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend a factory reset (Advanced > System Tools > Backup & Restore > Factory Default Restore > Factory Restore). Be sure to upgrade the firmware afterwards, and then try again.

Comment: I've checked if there is a newer version first thing, and there isn't.
secondly, it turns out I can get away if I enter my custom IP twice: both as primary address and also as my secondary address, weird..